# How to change URL's like ?id=223 into SEO Friendly URL's

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change this URL:

```
example.com/movie/?id=50&movie=Iron-Man
```

into

```
example.com/movie/50-Iron-Man
```

I did some research and looks like I need to edit my `.htaccess` file.

I tried few things, but it does not work.

This is all what is inside my `.htaccess` file currently.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/error404.php


php_flag display_errors 1
```

I think it will be better, If I do not write all things that I tried to get it done, according to me, it will just make the question more confusing.

Comment: But yes, you will have to mention your previous attempts. These questions are posted daily, and yet another one will not benefit future users with just "does not work". It's covered in the linked reference otherwise..

Answer (score 0):

Use routing option..
For example in codeignitor(php) $route['post/upvote'] = "PostController/upVote";